# Show that $\frac{\sin(c\left | x \right |)}{4\pi \left | x \right |}$ is a solution of $\Delta u+c^{2}u=0$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $c$ is positive and in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ we define $$u(x)=\frac{\sin(c\left | x \right |)}{4\pi \left | x \right |},$$ where $x$ is a vector and $|x|$ means its norm.
Then I want to show that this is a solution of $$\Delta u+c^{2}u=0,$$ but it seems that it isn't the solution after my long calculation. Here is my calculation:
[image: own calculations]
Can anyone tell me where is wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you differentiating $|x|$ just like that in your calculations? How did $x_i$ pop around?

Comment: x is a vector and hence $\left | x \right |$ means its norm and when differentiate it we get $x_{i}$

Comment: I'm also curious about what you got the derivative of $|x|$ to be? Shouldn't it be $x_i/|x|$? I'm not sure that's what you got.

Comment: Let $f(x)=\|x\|$. No the (partial) derivative of $f$ with respect to the $i$-th coordinate $x_i$ **isn't** $x_i$: it is $\dfrac{x_i}{\|x\|}$ !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $r:=|x|$ we have
$$
u = \frac{1}{4\pi} \frac{\sin(cr)}{r}.
$$

In spherical coordinates, and since we have no dependency on the angles, the [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Three_dimensions) is given by
$$
\Delta u 
= \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial r} u \right)
= \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^2 \frac{\partial }{\partial r} \left[ \frac{1}{4\pi} \frac{\sin(cr)}{r} \right]\right)
= \frac{1}{4\pi} \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^2 \frac{\partial }{\partial r} \left[ \frac{\sin(cr)}{r} \right]\right)
\\
= \frac{1}{4\pi} \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^2 \frac{c\cos(cr)\cdot r - \sin(cr)\cdot 1}{r^2} \right)
= \frac{1}{4\pi} \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( cr \cos(cr) - \sin(cr) \right)
\\
= \frac{1}{4\pi} \frac{1}{r^2} \left( c \cos(cr) - c^2 \sin(cr) - c\cos(cr) \right)
= - c^2 \frac{1}{4\pi} \frac{\sin(cr)}{r^2} 
= -c^2 u.
$$
Thus,
$$
\Delta u + c^2 u = 0.
$$